# Stand-alone Mail API in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, imap, blackberry-jde

Does anyone know of a stand-alone Mail API that works well with Blackberry? We're developing a client for a service that uses IMAP as a backend, but is not an IMAP Mail server.

JavaMail has everything that is needed but doesn't play nice with Blackberry's JRE. What I mean by this is that the method of connecting in javamail is Session.getInstance(Properties) and the Blackberry JRE doesn't have Properties.

Apache's Email doesn't work because I need to be able to both receive and send messages.

While blackberry does provide a javamail hack in it's system, it's not something that was maent to be used like this.

Are there any open alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LogicMail](http://www.logicprobe.org/proj/logicmail/wiki/features) (opensource application, BlackBerry API)

- IMAP, POP, SMTP, SSL (in SMTP - dedicated ports only)
- MIME message structure decoding

[mujMail](http://www.mujmail.xf.cz/index.php) (opensource application, J2ME API)

- IMAP4, POP3, SMTP, SSL supported
- Supports basic mail attachments like *.png, *.jpg, *.gif images